# Read a text file and transfer contents to mysql database table using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to data base handling using python programming.
                  By using python programming ,i want to read raw text file which consist of STUDEN T_NAME,STUDENT_MARKS. Which are separated by pipe symbol(given as below Example),I want to push this data into student table consists of 2 columns (STUDENT_NAME,STUDENT_MARKS) with respective data values.

input data file will be like this(it consists of some thousands of records like this),my input file is .Dat file ,its start only with records,each line contain 0 or more number of records(there is no fixed count of records on each line),there is no other keyword appear anywhere else ::

> records    STUDENT_NAME| jack | STUDENT_MARKS|200| STUDENT_NAME| clark
>   |STUDENT_MARKS|200| STUDENT_NAME| Ajkir | STUDENT_MARKS|30| 
>   STUDENT_NAME| Aqqm | STUDENT_MARKS|200| STUDENT_NAME| jone | 
>   STUDENT_MARKS|200| STUDENT_NAME| jake | STUDENT_MARKS|100|

Output mysql table table::

> ### STUDENT_NAME| STUDENT_MARKS
>
> ```
>  jack   |   200
>  clark  |   200
> ```
>
> .......

please advice me to read file&push data in efficient way.
I would be so grateful if someone could give me script to achieve this.

Comment: Also describe exactly what is in the input file. Does it start with `records`? Does that keyword or any other keyword appear anywhere else? Does each line contain a single student record, or is there one long line with thousands of records?

Comment: hi gauden,my input file is .Dat file ,its start only with records,each line contain 0 or more number of records(there is no fixed count of records on each line),there is no other keyword appear anywhere else,please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

```
# import mysql module
import MySQLDB

# import regular expression module
import re

# set file name & location (note we need to create a temporary file because 
# the original one is messed up)

original_fyle = open('/some/directory/some/file.csv', 'r')
ready_fyle = open('/some/directory/some/ready_file.csv', 'w')


# initialize & establish connection 
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="username", passwd="password",db="database_name") 
cur = con.cursor()

# prepare your ready file 

for line in original_fyle:
    # substitute useless information this also creates some formatting for the 
    # actuall loading into mysql
    line = re.sub('STUDENT_NAME|', '\n', line) 
    line = re.sub('STUDENT_MARKS|', '', line)
    ready_fyle.write(line)

# load your ready file into db

# close file
ready_file.close()

# create a query 
query = 'load data local infile "/some/directory/some/ready_file.csv" into table table_name field terminated by "|" lines terminated by "\n" '
# run it 
cur.execute(query)
# commit just in case 
cur.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of [being kind to newcomers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), some code to get you started:

```
# assuming your data is exactly as in the original question
data = '''records STUDENT_NAME| jack | STUDENT_MARKS|200| STUDENT_NAME| clark |STUDENT_MARKS|200| STUDENT_NAME| Ajkir | STUDENT_MARKS|30| STUDENT_NAME| Aqqm | STUDENT_MARKS|200| STUDENT_NAME| jone | STUDENT_MARKS|200| STUDENT_NAME| jake | STUDENT_MARKS|100|'''

data  = data.split('|')

for idx in range(1, len(data), 4):
    # every second item in the list is a name and every fourth is a mark
    name = data[idx].strip() # need to add code to check for duplicate names
    mark = int(data[idx+2].strip()) # this will crash if not a number
    print(name, mark) # use these values to add to the database
```

You may want to play with [SQLite using this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/) to learn how to use such databases with Python.
And [this tutorial about file input](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/File_IO) may be useful.

You may want to start with this and then [come back with some code](http://whathaveyoutried.com).